# How would I convert this jquery code into to standard javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since [my cell phone apparently doesn't support JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190890/why-would-javascript-work-on-my-sony-ericsson-c510-browser-but-not-javascript/3190936#3190936), but does run the simple Javascript tests I have done, **how can I convert the following JQuery code into standard Javascript**?

All I need this to do is have basic **click-to-hide / click-to-show** functionality.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("div > div.question").mouseover(function() {
                    if($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
                        $(this).next().show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).next().hide();
                    }
                });    
            });        
        </script>
        <style>
            div.flashcard {
                margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
            }
            div.flashcard div.question {
                background-color:#ddd;
                width: 400px;        
                padding: 5px;    
                cursor: hand;    
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            div.flashcard div.answer {
                background-color:#eee;
                width: 400px;
                padding: 5px;    
                display: none;        
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="1" class="flashcard">
    <div class="question">Who was Wagner?</div>
    <div class="answer">German composer, conductor, theatre director and essayist.</div>
    </div>

    <div id="2" class="flashcard">
    <div class="question">Who was Thalberg?</div>
    <div class="answer">a composer and one of the most distinguished virtuoso pianists of the 19th century.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Worked!

Thanks bobince!

[image]
<sub>(source: [deviantsart.com](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/o61pba.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't got a NetFront to test this on, but, trying to keep it relatively unflashy to hopefully avoid broken browser features:

```
window.onload= function() {
    var divs= document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i= divs.length; i-->0;)
        if (divs[i].className==='question')
            Toggler(divs[i]);
};

function Toggler(div) {
    var state= false; // assume initially hidden
    var toggled= div.nextSibling;
    while (toggled.nodeType!==1)
        toggled= toggled.nextSibling; // find next element sibling

    div.onclick= function() {
        state= !state;
        toggled.style.display= state? 'block' : 'none';
    };
};
```

I made it use the `click` event rather than toggling on every `mouseover`, which seemed a bit strange (and unlikely to work on a mouseless phone).

(Incidentally, avoid purely numeric `id` attribute values. It's not valid and can cause odd behaviours.)

Answer (score 1):

Another verbose answer

```
window.onload = function(){
  var questions = getElementsByClass('question',document,'div');

  for (var idx=0;idx<questions.length;idx++)
      questions[idx].onclick = function(){
              var answer = getElementsByClass('answer',this.parentNode,'div')[0];

              if (answer.style.display == '')
                  answer.style.display='block'
              else
                  answer.style.display = '';
          }
}

function getElementsByClass(searchClass,node,tag) {
    var classElements = new Array();
    if ( node == null )
        node = document;
    if ( tag == null )
        tag = '*';
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var elsLen = els.length;
    var pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+searchClass+"(\\s|$)");
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
            classElements[j] = els[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return classElements;
}
```

live at http://www.jsfiddle.net/WTRFS/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="1" class="flashcard" onclick="if (this.style.display == '') this.style.display='none'; else this.style.display = ''">
card contents
</div>
```

Quick and dirty :)

Comment: also, you can create a function (not sure if your phone will support that... smth like:

function showhideme(element) {
element.style.display = element.style.display == '' ? 'none' : '';
}

...
<div onclick='showhideme(this)'></div>